# "Your Google Cloud Platform/API project is now ready for you to fix any compliance issues." but VM status is still blocked, what i suppose to do now?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Got a mail saying "Based on either additional information you provided or further analysis we performed, we have reinstated resources associated with the project." but still unable to start the VM.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "Unable to start the VM"?  What recipe / procedure are you following?  What messages or status do you see?  Please try and be as verbose as possible.  Experience shows that time spent on the quality and content of a question pays itself back over and over again.  Don't make any assumptions about the readers.

Comment: Why was your access revoked in the first place?